# In android how to send complex array in magento using ksoap2 library?

Tags: java, php, android, magento, ksoap2

Complex Array Like :

```
$id = "value";

$customer = array("key" => "value", "key" => "value");

$set = $soap->call($sessionID, 'abc.set', array($id, $customer));
```

How to send request form android with this type of complex array in soap.

I am using `ksoap2` library for sending request in magneto soap.

In SoapUi Software formatting of calling this type of complex array like :

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:Magento" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <call>
         <sessionId xsi:type="xsd:string">??</sessionId>
         <resourcePath xsi:type="xsd:string">abc.set</resourcePath>
         <args xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array">
            <item xsi:type="xsd:int">id</item>
            <item xsi:type="ns2:Map">
               <item>
                  <key xsi:type="xsd:string">key</key>
                  <value xsi:type="xsd:string">value</value>
               </item>
               <item>
                  <key xsi:type="xsd:string">key</key>
                  <value xsi:type="xsd:string">value</value>
               </item>
               <item>
                  <key xsi:type="xsd:string">key</key>
                  <value xsi:type="xsd:string">value</value>
               </item>
            </item>
         </args>
      </call>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: i got the solution https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ksoap2-android/OeP-jWVLZMw

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1 :** In ksoap or ksoap2 no direct support to send Array. so you can create a SoapObject with method name(which you need to create array)

```
SoapObject object= new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,"shoppingCartProductEntity");
object.addProperty("product_id","886");
object.addProperty("sku","ABC 456-Black-10");
         and more parameters.....
```

**Step 2 :** then create arrayType method(optional depends on your WSDL) and add this soapObject to that array Object as a property

```
SoapObject EntityArray = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "shoppingCartProductEntityArray");
EntityArray.addProperty("products",object);
```

**Step 3 :** finally add the array to your main soap call

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,"shoppingCartProductAdd");
request.addProperty("sessionId", sessionId);
request.addProperty("quoteId", cartId);
request.addProperty("products",EntityArray); //ADDING ARRAY HERE AS A PEOPERTY
env.setOutputSoapObject(request);
androidHttpTransport.call(NAMESPACE +"/shoppingCartProductAdd ", env);
resultSoap = env.getResponse();
```

NOTE : the steps varies depends on the your WSDL, sometimes you can directly add 1st step object as a parameter, this depends on WSDL.

Comment: I tried it but I'm getting this error 'SoapFault - faultcode: '1022' faultstring: 'Please specify the product required option(s).'. Any solution for this?