# how to send keypair valuie using ksoap2 library in android?

Tags: php, android, magento, cordova, android-ksoap2

I want to send key-pair values in soap web Service using ksoap2 library in android.

Like :

```
Map<String,String> map = new  Map<String,String>();
map.put(key,value);
map.put(key,value);

Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();
vector.add(10);
vector.add(map);
```

Now this vector send in **ksoap2** library then its give serialization error.
if another way to send this map in **ksoap2** library.

Comment: Why the duplicate ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17342327/in-android-how-to-send-complex-array-in-magento-using-ksoap2-library

Comment: This is not duplicate. I just asked about serialization error and asked about solution of this error.

Comment: Update your previous question instead of creating a new one..

Comment: i got the solutiuon ...  Hashtable hashtable = new Hashtable();
hashtable.put("is_report", false);
hashtable.put("r_how", 1);
_client.addProperty("params",hashtable);

SoapSerializationEnvelope _envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
 _envelope.bodyOut = _client;
HttpTransportSE _ht = new HttpTransportSE("http://www.drebedengi.ru/soap/");
_ht.debug = true;     
(new MarshalHashtable()).register(_envelope);

Answer (score 0):

i got the solutiuon ...

```
Hashtable hashtable = new Hashtable();
hashtable.put("is_report", false);
hashtable.put("r_how", 1); 
_client.addProperty("params",hashtable);
SoapSerializationEnvelope _envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); 
_envelope.bodyOut = _client; 
HttpTransportSE _ht = new HttpTransportSE("drebedengi.ru/soap/"); 
_ht.debug = true; 
(new MarshalHashtable()).register(_envelope);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your using Ksoap2: you can do like this also....

```
//creating object of soap with parameter name
    SoapObject param = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,"shoppingCartProductEntity");
    param.addProperty("product_id","886");
    param.addProperty("sku","ABC 456-Black-10");

/* creating array of the product details 
    SoapObject EntityArray = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "shoppingCartProductEntityArray");
    EntityArray.addProperty("products",param); */

//normal soap call 
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,"shoppingCartProductAdd");
        request.addProperty("sessionId", sessionId);
        request.addProperty("quoteId", cartId);
        request.addProperty("products",param (or) EntityArray);  //adding array to cart
        env.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        androidHttpTransport.call(NAMESPACE +"/shoppingCartProductAdd ", env);
        resultSoap = env.getResponse();
        Log.d("****result****", resultSoap.toString());
```